# R sum an array along a specified dimension

Tags: r, list, rowsum

I am looking for a way to sum an array along a specified dimension.

I was able to reproduce the example given in the [MathWorks documentation for MATLAB](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html). My R code refers to the following part of the MATLAB documentation:

```matlab
A = ones(4,2,3);
S = sum(A,3)

%  Result:
%  S = 4×2  

%     3     3
%     3     3
%     3     3
%     3     3
```

An eqivalent in R would be:

```r
matlabsum = matrix(1, 4*2*3)
dim(matlabsum) = matrix(c(4,2,3))
matlabsum
matlabsumEquivalent = rowSums(matlabsum,dims=2)
matlabsumEquivalent
```

This returns the same result as in MATLAB.
Now I am trying to replicate some MATLABcode in R.
The MATLAB code looks like this (4 dimensions):

```
FtTEST = ones(2,3,3,16);
FtTESTsum = sum(FtTEST,4)
```

Same in R:

```r
Ftmatlabsum = matrix(1, 2*3*3*16)
dim(Ftmatlabsum) = matrix(c(2,3,3,16))
Ftmatlabsum
FtmatlabsumEquivalent = rowSums(Ftmatlabsum,dims=3) # dims is: dims+1 with rowSums
FtmatlabsumEquivalent
```

My actual attempt in R is to apply the `rowSums()` function to a list that looks like this:

```r
FtTEST = vector("list", 2*3*3*16)
dim(FtTEST) = matrix(c(2,3,3,16))
FtTEST[FtTEST == "NULL"] = 1 # Filling list with values of 1
Ftsum = rowSums(FtTEST,dims=3) # dims+1
Ftsum # ERROR
```

I only get `Error in rowSums(FtTEST, dims = 3) : 'x' must be numeric` as Error.

How do I convert my list properly?

Comment: Why not convert the list to an array? One way , I think, is `un = unlist(FtTEST); dim(un) = dim(FtTEST)`

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: FtTESTarr <- array(as.numeric(unlist(FtTEST)), dim = c(2, 3, 3, 16))
It then does rowSums() on it. Thanks!!

Comment: I feel like you can make this question a lot more understandable to an R user who doesn't understand MATLAB by simply removing all MATLAB references. All `sum(A,dim)` does, is sum a (multi-) dimensional matrix along the specified axis. That's a basic operation, which in my opinion, would not need an example in a different language.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
FtTESTarr <- array(as.numeric(unlist(FtTEST)), dim = c(2, 3, 3, 16))
```

It then does `rowSums()` on it. Thanks to "user20650"!!